# next js 404 when refresh dynamic route

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js

I have error 404 not found when refresh page with dynamic routes ini next js, my structure page is like below:

```
pages
  [storeName]
     summaries.jsx
     [store-insight].jsx
```

when I'm in `[store-insight].jsx` I need the query in url to be used in hitting an api. for example `www.url.com/storName/10`, I use the `10` in an api body.

*Note: when I refresh the page from `localhost`, everything is fine.

here is the code in `[store-insight].jsx`:

```
  import { useRouter } from 'next/router';
  import { useEffect, useState } from 'react';
  import { BackButton } from '../../components/button/BackButton';
  import Navbar from '../../components/Navbar';
  import { useSelector } from 'react-redux';
  import { StoreInsightHeader } from '../../components/storeInsight/StoreInsightHeader';
  import { KeyValueInsight } from '../../components/storeInsight/KeyValueInsight';
  import { StoreInsightSummaryChart } from '../../components/storeInsight/StoreInsightSummaryChart';

  const StoreInsight = () => {
    const { back, query } = useRouter();
    const router = useRouter();

    const {
      store,
      filterReport,
      revenuInsight,
      featuresInsight,
      productInsight,
      browsingInsight,
      operationalGraph,
    } = useSelector((store) => store);
    // const { detailStore } = store;
    // const { name, country_code, location } = detailStore;

    const [storeDetail, setStoreDetail] = useState({});

    const storeDetails = () => {
      const splitted = query['store-insight']?.split('&');
      setStoreDetail((prev) => {
        return {
          ...prev,
          id: splitted[0],
          storeName: splitted[1],
          storeLocation: splitted[2],
          storeLogo: splitted[3],
        };
      });
    };

    useEffect(() => {
      if (query['store-insight']?.length > 0) storeDetails();
    }, [query, storeDetail?.id]);

    return (
      <>
        <div className='bg-white'>
          <Navbar storeLogo={storeDetail?.storeLogo} />
        </div>
        <div className='m-6 flex flex-1 flex-row items-center space-x-3'>
          <BackButton
            onClick={() => {
              router.push({
                pathname: `/${query?.storeName}/summaries`,
                query: { date: filterReport?.filter },
              });

              localStorage.removeItem('storeDetail');
            }}
            className={'h-3 w-3'}
          />
          <label className='text-[10px] font-bold'>
            Back to Account Level Insights
          </label>
        </div>
        <div className='bg-white p-4 rounded-lg mx-4'>
          <StoreInsightHeader
            storeName={`${storeDetail?.storeName} ${storeDetail?.storeLocation}`}
          />
          <KeyValueInsight />
          <StoreInsightSummaryChart />
        </div>
      </>
    );
  };

  export default StoreInsight;
```

also used in `<KeyValueInsight />` component ini `[store-insight].jsx` page like below:

```
import { useRouter } from 'next/router';
import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import { useDispatch, useSelector } from 'react-redux';
import {
  setKeyInsight,
  setValueCreated,
} from '../../features/InsightV2/storeMetricSlice';
import { key_value_insight } from '../../resource/dummy-data';
import { getStoreMetric } from '../../services/insightV2/storeMetric';
import { KeyValueInsightCard } from '../card/KeyValueInsightCard';
import BrowsingInterestSkeleton from '../skeleton/BrowsingInterest';
import { convertInputPrice } from '../../helper/priceConverter';

export const KeyValueInsight = () => {
  const { query } = useRouter();
  const dispatch = useDispatch();
  const { store, filterReport, storeMetric } = useSelector((store) => store);
  const { filter, custom_date } = filterReport;
  const { key_insight, value_created } = storeMetric;

  const [loading, setLoading] = useState(false);
  const [storeDetail, setStoreDetail] = useState({});

  const storeDetails = () => {
    const splitted = query['store-insight']?.length && query['store-insight']?.split('&');

    setStoreDetail((prev) => {
      return {
        ...prev,
        id: splitted[0],
        storeName: splitted[1],
        storeLocation: splitted[2],
        storeLogo: splitted[3],
      };
    });
  };

  const currency = () => {
    if (storeDetail?.storeName === 'al-ikhsan') {
      return `MYR`;
    } else {
      return `SGD`;
    }
  };

  const fetchData = async () => {
    try {
      setLoading(true);
      if (filter === 'custom') {
        const { data } = await getStoreMetric({
          days: filter,
          storeId: storeDetail?.id,
          customStart: custom_date?.custom_start,
          customeEnd: custom_date?.custom_end,
        });

        if (data) {
          dispatch(setKeyInsight(data?.key_insight));
          dispatch(setValueCreated(data?.value_created));
        }
      } else {
        const { data } = await getStoreMetric({
          days: filter,
          storeId: storeDetail?.id,
        });

        if (data) {
          dispatch(setKeyInsight(data?.key_insight));
          dispatch(setValueCreated(data?.value_created));
        }
      }
    } catch (error) {
      console.log('store metric chart log <<<<<<', error);
    } finally {
      setLoading(false);
    }
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    if (query['store-insight']?.length > 0) storeDetails();
  }, [query]);

  useEffect(() => {
    if (storeDetail?.id) fetchData();
  }, [storeDetail?.id, filter, custom_date]);

  return (
    <div className='grid grid-cols-2 mt-4 gap-x-4'>
      <div className='p-4 rounded-lg border'>
        <div className='font-semibold text-xs mb-4'>Key Insights</div>
        {loading ? (
          <BrowsingInterestSkeleton />
        ) : (
          <div className='grid text-center grid-cols-4 gap-x-4'>
            <KeyValueInsightCard
              title={'Capture'}
              value={key_insight?.capture?.value || 'WIP'}
            />
            <KeyValueInsightCard
              title={'Browsing'}
              value={key_insight?.browsing?.value || 'WIP'}
            />
            <KeyValueInsightCard
              title={'Leads'}
              value={key_insight?.leads?.value || 'WIP'}
            />
            <KeyValueInsightCard
              title={'Conversion'}
              value={key_insight?.conversion?.value || 'WIP'}
            />
          </div>
        )}
      </div>
      <div className='p-4 rounded-lg border'>
        <div className='font-semibold text-xs mb-4'>Value Created</div>
        {loading ? (
          <BrowsingInterestSkeleton />
        ) : (
          <div className='grid text-center grid-cols-4 gap-x-4'>
            <KeyValueInsightCard
              title={'Shoppers Served'}
              value={
                convertInputPrice(`${value_created?.shoppers_served?.value}`) ||
                'WIP'
              }
            />
            <KeyValueInsightCard
              title={'Time Saved'}
              value={
                convertInputPrice(`${value_created?.time_saved?.value}`) +
                ` min`
              }
            />
            <KeyValueInsightCard
              title={'Shoppers Acquired'}
              value={value_created?.shoppers_acquired?.value || 'WIP'}
            />
            <KeyValueInsightCard
              title={'Sales Generated'}
              value={
                `${currency()} ${parseFloat(
                  value_created?.sales_generated?.value,
                ).toFixed()}.00` || 'WIP'
              }
            />
          </div>
        )}
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found the solution for my problem, maybe anyone who got same error can try this solution. I rename the `[store-insight].jsx` to `[storeinsight].jsx` and it worked. I guess next doesn't allow to have `-` in dynamic page.